# Please help me how to delete the files in one folder which are more than 60 days old in UNIX

Tags: shell

I know how to delete the files the files which are more than 60 days old. But I have to satisfy below conditions. Please help me to get correct script to automate this.

I have below files for each day on monthly basis. So I have these files for last 3 years.

```
vtm_data_12month_20140301.txt
vtm_data_12month_20140301.control
vtm_mtd_20130622.txt
vtm_mtd_20130622.control
vtm_ytd_20131031.txtvtm_ytd_20131031.control
```

I'd like to write a script find the all files which are more than 60 days old and delete them all but except last month file.

Suppose for january I want to keep the last file (latest) `vtm_data_12month_20140131.txt` and delete all 30 files. Issue here is, there is chance that I might have files received for January 30th, so in that case I should not delete the latest file, but I have to delete the rest.

Please advice me how can we achieve this via shell script. Your response is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. The two primary approaches are either to **(1)** use the `actual file date` to determine whether the files are removed or **(2)** use the `date embedded in the filename` to determine the file date. Both have advantages and pitfalls. What you seem to be asking is to remove files 60 days older than the latest date embedded in the filename or **2**.

As you have indicated, you may have a number of files with dates mixed relatively close to the end and you may need to adjust the date. Rather than just having the script parse for a maximum file date string contained in the file, you can prompt for the `end date` to measure 60 days back from. Otherwise, just scan each embedded date and find the max, and subtract 60 days from there. The following script prompts for an `end_date`.

In fact, the following script contains code to remove files by **both methods** (and sample data). The code to remove based on the actual file create date ( **(1) above** ) is commented out below the code that uses the embedded date. Look over the script and understand what it does. It is fairly well commented. **NOTE** the actual `rm` command **is commented out** to prevent accidents (even though it requires you to enter **YES** to confirm removal). Uncomment the `rm` line to be able to actually remove files. Drop a comment if you have questions:

```
#!/bin/bash

oifs="$IFS"     # save current IFS (internal field separator) (default ' \t\n')
IFS=$'\n'       # set IFS to only break on space

## prompt for path containing files & read
printf "\n enter the path to files to remove (no ending '/'): "
read -r rmpath

## validate directory
[ -d "$rmpath" ] || { printf "\nerror: bad path '%s'\n\n" "$rmpath"; exit 1; }

## prompt for ending date of files to keep
printf "\n enter the _end_ date of files to keep 'yyyymmdd' : "
read -r enddatestr

IFS="$oifs"     # reset IFS to original

enddt=$(date -d "$enddatestr" +%s)      # get enddt in seconds since epoch
enddt=$((enddt - (60 * 24 * 3600)))     # subtract 60 days

declare -a rmarray

## Using embedded filename date
mdate=$(date -d "@$enddt" +%Y%m%d)      # get mdate string to compare to filename

## fill rmarray with file dates older than mdate
for i in $(find "$rmpath" -maxdepth 1 -type f); do

    ffname="${i##*/}"       # full filename component
    fname=${ffname%.*}      # filename w/o extension
    fdate="${fname##*_}"    # get file date string
    ## if fdate before mdate, add to remove array
    [ "$mdate" -gt "$fdate" ] && rmarray+=( "$i" )

done

# ### Using actual file creation date
# tgtfile=/tmp/tgt_$(date +%s)            # tmp filename to measure against
# 
# ## create temp file to measure against with find & set trap to remove
# touch -t $(date -d "@${enddt}" +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S) "$tgtfile" &&
# trap 'rm -rf "$tgtfile"' 0
# 
# ## fill array with filenames to remove
# rmarray=( $(find "$rmpath" -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -newer $tgtfile) )

## verify files are contained in rmarray
[ "${#rmarray[@]}" -lt 1 ] && {    
    printf "\n No files matched the dates for removal.\n\n"
    exit 1
}

## print files that will be removed
printf "\n ** the following files will be removed **\n\n"

for i in "${rmarray[@]}"; do

    ls -al "$i"

done

## prompt for actual removal
printf "\n Continue with ACTUAL removal (YES to remove) : "
read ans

if [ "$ans" = "YES" ]; then
    for i in "${rmarray[@]}"; do

        # rm "$i"   # NOTE: 'rm' is commented, uncomment to really delete

    done
else
    printf "\n You entered '%s' (not YES), no removal performed.\n\n" "$ans"
fi

exit 0
```

**test directory:**

```
$ls -l dat/fstst
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Nov 27 01:10 vtm_data_12month_20140301.control
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Nov 27 01:10 vtm_data_12month_20140301.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Nov 27 01:10 vtm_mtd_20130622.control
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Nov 27 01:10 vtm_mtd_20130622.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Nov 27 01:10 vtm_ytd_20131031.control
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Nov 27 01:10 vtm_ytd_20131031.txt
```

**use:**

```
$ bash rmfiles_60days.sh

 enter the path to files to remove (no ending '/'): dat/fstst

 enter the _end_ date of files to keep 'yyyymmdd' : 20140301

 ** the following files will be removed **

-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Nov 27 01:10 dat/fstst/vtm_mtd_20130622.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Nov 27 01:10 dat/fstst/vtm_ytd_20131031.control
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Nov 27 01:10 dat/fstst/vtm_ytd_20131031.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Nov 27 01:10 dat/fstst/vtm_mtd_20130622.control

 Continue with ACTUAL removal (YES to remove) : YES
```

**result:**

```
$ ls -l dat/fstst
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Nov 27 01:10 vtm_data_12month_20140301.control
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Nov 27 01:10 vtm_data_12month_20140301.txt
```

The following is an example using the actual file date:

**test directory:**

```
$ls -l dat/tst
total 324
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    74 Sep  9 01:23 1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    74 Sep  9 01:23 2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   201 Aug  1 03:47 3line.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   205 Aug  1 03:35 3line.dat.sav
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    88 Aug 13 04:05 catfile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    39 Jul  4 14:40 comma
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   291 Sep 23 03:00 createfile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    11 Jul 17 03:54 data.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david     8 Jul 17 03:54 datb.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   369 Oct  2 14:25 dia.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    36 Nov  6 15:51 dicta.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 23895 Sep  9 17:14 dna.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   243 Nov  4 23:07 domain.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   276 Nov 23 00:32 ecread.dat
(snip)
```

**use:**

```
$ bash rmfiles_60days.sh

 enter the path to files to remove (no ending '/'): dat/tst

 enter the _end_ date of files to keep 'yyyymmdd' : 20141031

 ** the following files will be removed **

-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 205 Aug  1 03:35 dat/tst/3line.dat.sav
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 29 Jun 29 02:23 dat/tst/f1f2.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 8 Jul 17 03:54 dat/tst/datb.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 60 Jul 27 23:24 dat/tst/vowels.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 134 Aug 11 00:32 dat/tst/outfile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 4622 Jun 26 02:49 dat/tst/single.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 99 Jul  4 14:51 dat/tst/hostnm
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 115 Aug  7 01:35 dat/tst/ltags.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 122 Aug 29 11:11 dat/tst/hh.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 509 Jul 21 17:28 dat/tst/orders.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 205 Jun 27 01:06 dat/tst/table.html
(snip)

 Continue with ACTUAL removal (YES to remove) : YES
```

**result:**

```
$ ls -l dat/tst
total 168
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    74 Sep  9 01:23 1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    74 Sep  9 01:23 2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   291 Sep 23 03:00 createfile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   369 Oct  2 14:25 dia.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    36 Nov  6 15:51 dicta.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 23895 Sep  9 17:14 dna.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   243 Nov  4 23:07 domain.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   276 Nov 23 00:32 ecread.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    93 Nov  2 21:43 empdata.dat
(snip)
```